# AJAX won't call the php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so I have a php file that brings information from a database about an user. My idea is that when an button is pressed I send the id to the php file and the get the user that corresponds. However I can't seem to execute the php file, and the ajax response is empty.

How can I fix this? Thank you for your help

EDIT: I removed the die function, and add the echo the $usuario array. Now i get it in the response but i have a dumb question: how do i access the data of that array? Thank you again

Comment: and can u plz share the code inside this file `editar_persona.php`

Comment: What do you mean by "the response is empty"?  Does that mean the AJAX code is successfully calling the PHP file and successfully getting a blank response?  If so then it sounds like the problem is server-side, not here.

Comment: @David yes, it's successful but it never returns anything

Comment: @JulieRuchel: Then the code you're showing us appears to be working.  Time to start debugging your PHP code.

Comment: What is contained in `response`?

Comment: Impossible to say what's wrong without seeing your php file.

Comment: Why do you call `die()` in your PHP code? Looks obvious to me why you see nothing in your response

Comment: i think u need to pass datatype from ajax.

Comment: @JaredSmith i added it

Comment: @NicoHaase to see if it would enter there. I get the same result with it or without it

Comment: @JulieRuchel you're unconditionally calling `die`, so your script will stop executing at that point and you'll get an empty response. I also don't see you `echo`ing anything in your script anywhere.

Comment: So, what happens there? What do you expect from that `die()` call?

Comment: Additionally, if you want to check what `$_GET` contains, try looking it up in your browser's network console first to see which data is **really** sent to the backend

Comment: use `die($usuario);` before `return $usuario;` and share the result

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM persona WHERE nro = $nro"` Don't do this. You're vulnerable to SQL injection. [Use parameterized queries.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/9029328)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
$("#editar").click(function(){
    var nro = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "editar_persona.php?nro="+nro,
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
    });
```

GET request uses URL to pass Data

Comment: Yeah, what about that? Can you explain how this solves the problem?

Comment: if i do that in the response i get the value of nro but not the user, it doesn't get to the php

Comment: @JulieRuchel: because u r using `die($nro);`

Comment: @devpro I still get nothing without it

Comment: If you want SQL result, you need to print out the result on screen.
In my oppinion, I might use echo json_encode($array); to print out the sql result. 
So, the code will change to
$usuario = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($usuario);

And you will get those result in json format  in respone variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 require_once 'constantes.php';
 require_once 'smarty.php';
 require_once 'verificar_rol.php';

 $nro = $_GET['nro'];
try{
   $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USUARIO,PASSWORD,DB);
   if($mysqli->connect_errno){
      throw new Exception("Error al conectarse a servidor Mysql");
   }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM persona WHERE nro = $nro";
   // here is some change
  $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)  
  if(!$resultado){
  // end change
    throw new Exception("Error al obtener los datos");
  }
  $usuario = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
  echo $usuario;

}catch(Exception $excepcion){
  $smarty->assign("error", 1);
  $smarty->assign("mensaje", $excepcion->getMessage());
 }
```

and this

```
$("#editar").click(function(){
    var nro = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "editar_persona.php",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {nro: nro},
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert(response);
    });
```

Try this